# Why base tag does not work for relative paths?

Tags: html, tags, radix

I have a `<base>` tag as below in `<head>` section of the page:

```
<base href="http://localhost/framework">
```

And a script as below which is relative (of course after `<base>`):

```
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
```

But when I open jQuery from firebug it shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body> 
Blah Blah Blah....
```

When I use the below link it's OK though:

```
<script src="http://localhost/framework/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
```

I looked for an answer everywhere, but it seems I'm doing my job right! So what is the problem?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

`/assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is not relative but absolute*, the `/` takes it to the root even with a `base` tag.

If you remove that `/`, it should make it relative off the current path, which, when a `base` tag is present would be `http://localhost/framework/`.

**Note:** You will also need to add a trailing `/` to the end of the `href`, to indicate that it's a folder.

Full working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/test/" />
<script src="assets/test.js"></script>
<body>
hi
</body>
</html>
```

`*` Actually depending on who you ask, it's still relative since it is relative off the current domain. But I prefer to call this absolute since it's signifying the path is from the root, based on the current domain. Although, I guess technically that makes it relative in the grand scheme of things, and absolute only in terms of the current domain. Whatever.

Comment: I have changed it to: assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js but no success. I've got 404 not found as I said.

Comment: @phpGeek Looking in Firebug (or F12 or whatever else), what URL is it attempting to request now?

Comment: See the `EDIT` part of my question.

Comment: @phpGeek I have added (tested) example code which shows this working. Add a trailing `/` to the `href`, you still need to remove the `/` before assets too.

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. Although paths starting with `/` are *absolute*, URLs containing such paths are actually called *relative URLs*. According to the specification, you should be able to resolve *relative URLs* against the `<base>` tag. A `relative URL` as defined by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1808 is simply a URL lacking a URL scheme component.

Comment: @Gili hence my very clear `*`. You can resolve relative URLs against the base, but not "absolute" (meaning with a `/` in this context).

Comment: @Gili Depending on the type of the path a relative URL is relative to either the path (`foo.html`), the location (`/foo`) or even only the scheme ( `//foo.com`) of an absolute URL. Relative URLs having an absolute path ARE resolved against an explicit base URL, but you would only note a difference if that base URL has a domain or scheme different from that of the URL of the current document.

Comment: Thought this would be helpful .. i was using a base href for my angular app and had the image with a leading slash and it would not load. so removing it worked

    src="/assets/img/CSC_arms.png"

Comment: "You will also need to add a trailing / to the end of the href" -> that is what solved my issue!

Comment: @RudiVisser what is the significance of trailing "/" ? I got a similar scenario and was searching everywhere for this. :)

Answer (score 18):

Try having your base tag like:

```
<base href="http://localhost/framework/">
```

and your script tag like:

```
<script src="assets/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
```