# asp dropdownlist postback not working in update panel when using <base> url in masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, selectedindexchanged

I am using, `<base href="http://localhost:80/">` in my master page for base url,

now when I am using `dropdownlist` control on content page (located in `localhost:80/directory1/directory2`) within update panel, `selectedindexchanged` event is not working.

I tried to figure out, but in network tab of `firefox` console I found that request is looking for content page at base `url` only that is at `localhost:80/contenpage.aspx` instead of `localhost:80/directory1/directory2/contenpage.aspx` and giving error

> The resource cannot be found.

Comment: did you set autopostback to true?

Comment: yes, I did and if I comment that base tag in masterpage everything works fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521011/why-base-tag-does-not-work-for-relative-paths               ___ please check if the above post works. Looks like it has something to do with absolute path and relative path

Comment: Hi @user2846413 above post solved my other issues of relative urls but my actual problem still persists.. still dropdownlist event is not getting fired.. because we do not supply any url to that event, I had binded server side event simply like we do in normal code..

Comment: Can you show us your .aspx and code-behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant circumstance is that the form action is set to a relative URL in ASP.NET by default:

```
<form id="ctl01" action="./webform1" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

If you use the `base` tag, you change the base path that the page uses to interpret relative URLs. In your case, the `base` URL points to a path that is obviously not able to serve the pages of the application. In order to fix this, I'd reconsider whether the `base` tag is necessary. If it is, it should point to a URL that is able to serve the pages of the application. In order to set the `base` path to the base path of the application dynamically, you can use the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    baseCtrl.Attributes["href"] = new Uri(Request.Url, "/").OriginalString;
}
```

As a work-around if you need to keep the `base` tag as it is, I've also tried to set the `form` action to an absolute URL by integrating the following code into the master page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Form.Action = Request.Url.OriginalString;
}
```

This worked in my small sample so that the page could execute the PostBack successfully. Though the form is posted back to the same location as if there was no `base` tag, there might be some side-effects because other resources on the page (e.g. CSS, JavaScript files and the like) might also be referenced with a relative URL and therefore be retrieved from another location. So I'd still propose to reevaluate the `base` tag before resorting to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you have some asp component with Autopostback="true" and ClientIdMode="Static", you have to use the triger!

like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPrinceOffuce" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myCustomDropdown" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="myCustomDropdown" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true"
</asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifiing absolute url in form's `action`.