# How to use relative paths in MAMP (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I set up my website in MAMP with Wordpress, but when navigating with relative paths the home is not set properly.

while / do refer to localhost:8888/mywebsite, /page-name do not refer to localhost:8888/mywebsite/page-name but to localhost:8888/page-name.

how can I fix it to navigate my website in MAMP using relative paths?

Comment: Try `page-name` (or if you want to be more explicit, `./page-name`) which will be relative to the path of the resource the url is found in. `/page-name` is an absolute path (although it's a relative URL), absolute path do not start with a `/`.

Comment: Try the [`base` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11521011/1287812)