# Get asset path in Laravel from within React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, typescript, webpack

I'm wondering what the best way is to get the asset path for things like images from inside a React component. I'm using Laravel, and the built-in `asset()` function that you can use in Blade files is exactly what I need, but I need it on the front-end in JS. Seems like Webpack territory, but I'm not sure what setting I need to modify.

The problem arises when my path is more than just the hostname, for example "localhost:3000/myproject/public" instead of just "localhost:3000".

Doing something like....

```
import myImage from '../../images/my-image.png'

...

<img src={myImage} />
```

results in a src path of "/images/my-image.png", which is not found, because the image actually resides at "/myproject/public/images/my-image.png"

In the past I've used the not-so-elegant solution of doing:

```
// react.blade.php
<body data-root-url={{ asset('') }}>
  ...
</body>

// helpers.js
export const rootUrl = document.querySelector('body').getAttribute('data-root-url')
```

While this hasn't gotten me into any trouble yet, I'm trying to find a better way, and I also started using Typescript recently and it (understandably) gets cranky about this because it technically could be null.

I've also tried the following in `webpack.mix.js`:

```
  mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/myproject/public/',
    },
  })
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect on image paths. Oddly enough though, this did work when running into a similar issue with code-splitting and looking for the JS chunks.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using the `<base>` tag in the head of your `index.html` file?

Comment: Interesting, haven't heard of that before. Doesn't seem to affect this though.

Comment: you are probably not using it properly then. `<base href="http://localhost:3000/myproject/public/">` in the head prior to any other element that uses an href attribute. localhost:3000/myproject/public

Comment: Yup that's what I'm doing. No dice.

Comment: check this then...lots or reasons for this to go wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521011/why-base-tag-does-not-work-for-relative-paths

Comment: Ah. Webpack is making "/images/my-image.png", with a leading slash, so I guess that's why `<base>` doesn't help. Guess this points again towards needing some sort of custom Webpack path...

Comment: Check out your config for `assetsPublicPath` and `assetsSubDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by adding a new controller in the `routes/web.php` file.

```
Route::get('assets/{path}', function ($path) {
    return response()->file(public_path("assets/$path"));
});
```

Then I added the images inside the folder `public/assets/img/test.jpg` and called it in my React component normally.

```
<Card sectioned>
  <EmptyState image="/assets/img/test.jpg">
  </EmptyState>
</Card>
```