# Why appending "/" to base-href removes the need of deploy url?

Tags: java, angular, build

My angular application is bundled and deployed together with a java application. Angular AOT build is placed in the folder `WebContent/app`.
While taking the AOT build,

1. If I specify `--base-href /app`, I'm getting 404 after loading the index.html. In that case, I have to add `--deploy-url /app/` during my build, for the application to be working properly.
2. But If I specify `--base-href /app/` then scripts, styles, and other resources are served correctly. And there's no need to specify `--deploy-url`

What I could observe is that If I don't append "/" to base-href, the server request made is using the context-root - http://localhost:9080/application-name/styles.***.css and when I append the "/", server context-root is appended with `app` - http://localhost:9080/application-name/**app**/styles.***.css

Why is adding "/" at the end of base-href make all this difference?
Could someone explain this behavior as I'm not able to find anything on docs?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, I found the answer. It is not related to Angular at all.

Tha `<base>` tag is part of HTML Specification: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

As MDN Doc says,

> The HTML < base> element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs in a document. There can be only one < base> element in a document.

It is used to specify the base of relative URLs.
So coming into my problem

1. When `<base href="/app">` is used, the browser treats the `href` as a file rather than a directory. So the base URL will not be prepended to relative URLs.
2. When `<base href="/app/">` is used, the browser treats it as a directory and all relative URLs will be prepended by base URL.

More can be found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11521034/9390292) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1889898/9390292)